# how to make visible menu in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I installed the classifieds theme in Wordpress.The menu which I created for the previous theme can be seen in my new theme, but it is not visible when I take my cursor on the menu den only I can see the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly share the URL of your website. I think this is css styling issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the superfish menu plugin is not setting the CSS properties correctly when hovering over the menu item.Modify like below

**sample css**

```
.nav2 li.sfHover ul, ul.nav2 li:hover ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #B3B3B3;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    visibility: visible!important;
    display: block!important;
}
```